# null, nill is string type in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, error-handling, runtime-error

```
//result: ok fine
NSString *email = [dataDic objectForKey:@"email"];
if([email isEqualToString:@"null"])
    email = nil;
if((![email length]) == 0)
    self.emailLbl.text = email;

// result: not fine
NSString *email = [dataDic objectForKey:@"email"];
if((![email length]) == 0 || (email != nil) )
    self.emailLbl.text = email;
```

In dictionary, email property value contained null value. My question is what is the type of nil? -> `if comparison email == nil || email == [NSNull null]` ?

Comment: You should use `[email isKindOfClass:NSString.class] && email.length != 0` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several values that are different from Objective-C perspective here:

1. `nil` (aka `null` in other languages)
2. `[NSNull null]` (a special marker value object)
3. `@""` (empty string)
4. `@"null"` (just a string with 4 characters)

If you write your `dataDic` from your app, and you know that your app handles it well, you don't have to check all the cases. Check only the ones you expect. For example, if your app only writes non-empty strings to the dictionary, but sometimes "email" is not there, you only have to check `nil`, because `objectForKey` returns `nil` if the value is not inside the dictionary.

On the other hand if you have obtained `dataDic` from a 3rd party API, decoded from JSON for example, then you should do the full checking:

1. [NSNull null] is placed inside the dictionary if JSON has `null` originally like `{"email":null}`
2. If the server API changed you might get some other structure than NSString there (although quite unlikely here).
3. `nil` is returned if you don't have the key/value at all.

You can rule out all the 3 checks at once by doing:

```
NSString *emailStr = nil;
id emailObj = [dataDic objectForKey:@"email"];
if ([emailObj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    emailStr = emailObj;
}
```

Note that you might not have to check for an empty string or nil before assigning to UILabel text, because those work fine and just erase the label text:

```
self.emailLbl.text = @"";
self.emailLbl.text = nil; // another way to erase
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check whether the key @"email" contain any value or not like (if its a String)

```
NSString *email=dic[@"email"];
if (email) {
    //do anything with email
}
```

if you want to check your object is Nil Or Null then do

```
if (!email || email == (id)[NSNull null]) {
    //email unavailable
}
```

Alternately you can call `[Obj isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]` on any object.

Comment: Check if `email` is a string before checking its length.

Comment: i mentioned that earlier in the question. it was just to give him a direction btw @Willeke you're right.